# How to change background color of multi select dropdown?

Tags: react-native, dropdown, multi-select

Hello i'm trying to change background color of multiselect dropdown in react native. There is no attribute to change color in list.

Here is my code :

```
<MultiSelect
       hideTags
       style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.1)',color:'#d1d0cf'}}
       items={this.state.serviceCategories}
       uniqueKey="id"
       ref={(component) => { this.multiSelect = component }}
       onSelectedItemsChange={selectedCategory => this.setState({ selectedCategory })}
       selectedItems={this.state.selectedCategory}
       selectText="Pick Items"
       searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Items..."
       onChangeInput={ (text)=> console.log(text)}
       altFontFamily="ProximaNova-Light"
       tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
       tagBorderColor="#CCC"
       tagTextColor="#CCC"
       selectedItemTextColor="#f673d7"
       selectedItemIconColor="#f673d7"
       itemTextColor="#d1d0cf"
       displayKey="name"
       searchInputStyle={{ backgroundColor:'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.1)',color:'#d1d0cf' }}
       submitButtonColor="#f673d7"
       submitButtonText="Submit"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already submitted in issues of that library [unable to change multiselect background color](https://github.com/toystars/react-native-multiple-select/issues/24)

So now you have 2 options.

Either wait for someone to do that task and update the library

Or you yourself do some changes in library, add `backgroundcolor` parameter and generate PR.

If it is not urgent for you, let me generate PR for you tonight, and than you can use that in your project.